# Continuity, functions and limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, continuity

> Does there exist some real number $c$ between 0 and 1 for which
>   $\sqrt[3] c + c = 1?$

Please someone help, I have no idea how to do this and I'm trying to teach myself limits in calculus as my teacher never comes in. Please anyone?

Comment: This title does not describe the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x)=x^3+x-1$$

$f $ is continuous at $ [0,1]$,

$$f(0)f(1)=-1<0$$
thus by IVT, there exists $a\in (0,1)$ such that $f(a)=0=a+a^3-1$.

now, put $c=a^3 \text{ or } a=\sqrt[3]{c}$.